# How do I make a new face from intersection of faces

Tags: faces, edges

I created two objects, a hollow tube and a frame that I need to join so that the tube opens into the frame.  I joined the two objects where I want them and I'm trying to remove the faces of the frame to open it up to the inner walls of the tube.  I can't figure out how to put edges along the path where the frame's faces meet the tube's faces.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd bet there was an easier way, but here's how I ended up solving this.  I created a new object from the vertices on the inside edge of the tube.  Then used that with a Boolean operation to cut a hole in the walls of the frame (though I had to move the frame away from the tube to make this work, then moved it back into place after the cut).